# Same form for Edit and New methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use same html form for `Edit` and `New` methods.

Controller methods:

```
def new 
    render "edit"
end

def edit
  if params[:id].present?
    @goat = Goat.find(params[:id])
  else
    @goat = Goat.new
  end
end
```

`Edit` form:

```
<% form_for @goat do |f| %>    
<%= f.text_field :title %> 
<%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

It works well for `Edit` method when @goat record exists, but for `New` method, when controller gives `@goat = Goat.new` I got an error:

`undefined method model_name for NilClass:Class`

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you add the code for your create method?

Comment: There are no code yet... Can this affect this error?

Comment: You said "in Create method I added render edit"...

Comment: Oh sorry! I misspelled methods. There should be "New" everywhere  instead of "Create". Fixed!

Comment: OK, can you share the source of your "new" method, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not actually setting the new `@goat` for your html.

In this code:

```
def new 
    render "edit"
end
```

This doesn't call the `edit` method on your controller; instead it goes straight to the view layer to render the `edit.html.erb` file. So there's no value for `@goat` set, and thus the error you get.

Better is code like what @user2191327 provided.  You should also look at what the scaffold would generate for your controller; it's a good guide to what idiomatic Rails looks like.

Answer (score 1):

if you only want to use the same html just use render :template

```rb
def new
  @goat = Goat.new
  render template: 'edit'
end

def edit 
  @goat = Goat.find(params[:id])
end
```

or better way: use render partial in templates edit.html && new.html

P.S. using action 'edit' instead 'new' not a good idea, so if you look in your routes.txt file, you will see that path to action includes :id of class instance.

Comment: Thanks! I didin't knew how to use it in the right way, but there was a part where I was wrong! Thanks again!